# Como inserir apenas alguns dos atributos

Tags: jpa, eclipse-link

estou utilizando JPA com eclipse link, queria inserir apenas alguns dados no banco, alguns dos atributos não são necessário salvar, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a annotation @Transient do JPA na propriedade que você não deseja serializar(não persistir), ex:

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Transient
private String zip;
```

[Annotation Type Transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html)